# How to customize the shopping cart?

Tags: 8, theming, commerce

This is a real puzzle, if I disable the image field of the display mode of variations, it is still displayed in the shopping cart.

Can someone explain to me how to customize the shopping cart ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I do not understand. The "Teaser" display mode does not exist and the other display modes are not listed in the view. Why ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the last screenshot it looks like you're using the teaser view mode in the cart view. However, in your first screenshot, it looks like you haven't enabled and configured the teaser view mode on the variations. Scroll down on that page, open the *Custom display settings*, select *Teaser*, and click *Save*.

Afterwards, hide the image from the teaser view mode by clicking on the `Teaser` link below the `Manage Display` tab.

Finally make sure to do this for all variation types you got, if you do it only on one bundle and add a product (variation) of another type to the cart, the change won't be reflected in the cart view.

It seems the above solution doesn't work as expected, although it used to work for me at some point.
Another solution you can try is removing the rendered order item completely from the view, then adding a new relationship from the order item to the product variation and eventually add only the specific fields of the product variation you want to display to the view's fields.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question and your answer does not work

Comment: You could try to switch to the Default view mode in the view, then changing the Default view mode of product variations and check if the change gets reflected. If that's the case, all you'd have to do is add the teaser view mode for product variations via `/admin/structure/display-modes/view`

I'm not sure why, but the select widget with the view modes seems to allow selection of values that don't make sense.

Comment: I have already tested this but it does not work. Actually, the display modes in the product variation view are meaningless and do not correspond to anything.

Comment: Edited my answer and added another possible solution.